# Mapping in Domain Driven Design

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mapping, domain-driven-design, domain-events

I'm currently trying to find a way to map from one object to another where the first one is a domain model and the other one is an object that represents the same thing, but for a completely different use. A simple example:

```
public class SnmpDeviceService {

    private readonly Dictionary<int, 3rdPartyLibObj> devices;
    private SnmpLibrary snmp;

    public SnmpDeviceService() {
        snmp = new SnmpLibrary();
        snmp.ObjOnlineEvent += DeviceOnlineEvent;
    }

    public void Add(MyDevice device) {
        3rdPartyLibObj libObj = new 3rdPartyLibObj(device.IpAddress);
        devices.Add(device.Id, libObj);
        snmp.Observe(libObj);
    }

    public void DeviceOnlineEvent(object sender, args) {
        // Question here!
    }
```

**Question**

I've now received libObj (that is not mine) back with additional information. I would like to invoke a domain event now, but another service that listens for a certain domain event doesn't know the type 3rdPartyLibObj, he only knows MyDevice. How can I now map from 3rdPartyLibObj to MyDevice if they represent the same thing but look different? And if I want to keep MyDevice during the time I wait for the DeviceOnlineEvent, how should I reference it in my dictionary to keep MyDevice and 3rdPartyLibObj in context?

Like this?:

```
public Dictionary<int id, Tuple<MyDevice, 3rdPartyLibObj>>();
```

Comment: Instead of saving a tuple it would be better to create an object that wraps MyDevice and your 3rdPartyLibObj class. I don't know the capabilities of 3rdPartyLibObj, but I would prefer any events to be triggered directly on this wrapper object and be dispatched further to any other observers from there as a domain event.

Answer (score 0):

If `LibObj` is not your, why you use it in your context ?

Tell me if I misunderstood your problem... In your context (bounded context well defined ?) the object that you use for this stuff is MyDevice and `3rdPartyLibObj` comes from different context (so how different context communicate ? Do you thought with [Context Map](http://www.infoq.com/articles/ddd-contextmapping) or something like that ?). If it is exact, I recommand you to limit the use of `3rdPartyLibObj` in your context (using an anticorruption layer ?).